# federated authentication with ACS

Tags: azure, asp.net-4.0, acs, adfs2.0

I am trying to create a sample application here with federated authentication with Azure  ACS 
I have a asp.net web application with a  default.aspx page
I want to upload this azure cloud.I want to authenticate users using Active Directory login credentials how can I create an working sample for this.
I was searching and I found I can make use of Custom STS ?Is this the right direction ?
I found an example from MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_windowsazureandpassivefederation2010_topic2#_Toc310436991
but I clouldn't make this working till now. (I am getting a message --This page can't be displayed).
Can some one point me to a working sample with  step by step documentation.
I am using VS2010 on Windows8 machine,and azure sdk 1.7

I dont have an ADFS2.0 supported server machine available now.So I am just trying to make MSDN example working

I followed all the steps as mentioned [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_windowsazureandpassivefederation2010_topic2),but 
when I debug ,I can see control reaches inside  "WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider method"

if my assumption is right,it should redirect to Login.aspx page ,
but instead is simply showing message "This page cant be displayed"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the how-to guide on windowsazure.com: [How to Authenticate Web Users with Windows Azure Access Control Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/access-control/). This will also work for Active Directory by simply using your ADFS as an identity provider instead of Windows Live / Google, no need to create a custom STS for this.

If you want something with a little more screenshots, I wrote the following guide for one of my trainings: http://sandrinodimattia.net/blog/posts/federated-authentication-with-azure-appfabric-acs-v2-0-part-1-setup/

Comment: I dont have an ADFS2.0 supported server machine available now.So I am just trying to make MSDN example working

Comment: Well then you can simply use Windows Live as identity provider. Works just the same.